# Select Case to get the MAX value and output a different value when row is null

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying check if the rows is null and then if its null output the value 0.000 and then if its not get the MAX value, I've tried a few case statements but I cant get it to work properly, im always getting a syntax error.

This is my original query I used before testing:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0123" THEN value END),3) C1, 
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0124" THEN value END),3) C2,    
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0125" THEN value END),3) C3,   
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0126" THEN value END),3) C4,  
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0127" THEN value END),3) C5, 
  ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN id = "0128" THEN value END),3) C6 

FROM table1
WHERE id IN ("0123", "0124", "0125", "0126", "0127", "0128") and
FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000) BETWEEN "2014-11-01 09:00:00" AND "2014-11-01 12:00:00"
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 1
```

One of the queries i tested is I changed my select query to this. (Since I was only testing this before, I tried just getting the output of one column but still a syntax error)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,

    CASE id
          WHEN 0123 THEN ROUND(MAX(value),3)
          CASE WHEN id
          WHEN 0123 AND IS NULL THEN 0.000
        END
      END AS C1

FROM table1
WHERE id IN ("0123") and
FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000) BETWEEN "2014-11-01 09:00:00" AND "2014-11-01 12:00:00"
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000)) DIV 1
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement should look like

```
CASE WHEN id = 0123 THEN ROUND(MAX(value),3)
   WHEN id = 0123 OR id IS NULL THEN 0.000
  ELSE NULL
  END AS C1
```

Per comment

```
CASE WHEN id = 0123 THEN ROUND(MAX(value),3)
   WHEN id = 0123 AND value IS NULL THEN 0.000
  ELSE NULL
  END AS C1
```

Comment: on WHEN id = 0123 AND id IS NULL THEN 0.000 don't you mean and value is null?

Comment: @hocuspocus31, good catch. That should be a `OR` condition rather. Yes, it may be value is null but was not sure from your post. check edited answer.